# Is it possible to test API endpoints with Playwright just like Cypress?

Tags: api, automation, automated-tests, cypress, playwright

I have been using Cypress for a while now but this new kid on the block has arrived, Playwright which resolves some of the pain points I had with Cypress. The best usage I have with Cypress though is using it as a central repository for both my API and UI tests.
I was just wondering if this is possible with Playwright (and yes, I tried to google and check their documentation but maybe I missed something as it doesn't seem too explicit)

For example, I have this test with assertions on body, status, and properties.
`cypress/support/commands.js` (custom command)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('something', (method) => { // api for something
  return cy.request({
      method: method,
      url: 'https://something.com/api/',
      auth: {
        bearer: '12332asa42412412asda341'
      },
      body: 
        'description': 'this is my description'
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      failOnStatusCode: false // test all status codes
  });
});
```

`cypress/integration/apitest.js` (actual test)

```js
   cy.something('POST').should((resp) => {
      expect(resp.status).to.eq(201);
      expect(resp.headers).to.have.property('content-type', 'application/json');
      expect(resp.body.description).to.eq('this is my description');
    });
```

Comment: Possible to just use `fetch`?  - playwright is a js library to run your gui, so add your own api library

Comment: Playwright has soon an integration for making http request, see here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5999

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with this version `1.18-rc1`, I believe it is now enabled (though I haven't tried it yet but syntax is similar to Cypress API tests). This makes me consider Playwright more:
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing